# How to run two Simulink models in parallel (in terms of matlab cycle count)? Both models have different configuration parameters

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, simulink

I want to run two simulink model in parallel in such a way that they have same simulation time at any instant. Both model have same fixed step size (Fundamental sample time). Both models have different configuration parameter. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I have opened matlab twice and started simulating models but at any instance simulation time for both models are not same. How to make it same?

Answer (score 2):

I would put both models in a top-level model as referenced models, e.g.:

[image]

This will ensure that both models have the exact same simulation time at any instant. More on model referencing in the [Simulink documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/overview-of-model-referencing.html).

Comment: When you are putting two models in top level model as refrenced models, their configuration parameter should be same. But My requirement says that models have diff configuration parameter e.g Hardware Implementation parameter is different.

Comment: @Ranjan That's not true. You need to use [`configsets`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/more-about-configuration-sets.html) and attach the relevant `configset` to each referenced model. See [Simulink Model Referencing Requirements](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/simulink-model-referencing-requirements.html) in the doc for more details.

Comment: Hi @am304 I attached corresponding configsets to the model then tried ruuning them But I am getting below error of Hardware parameter mismatch (I used TI hardware for one model and Generic for others).

Error in Model block 'Ranjan_Test/Subsystem': the hardware settings must match between the parent model 'Ranjan_Test' and the referenced model 'Subsystem'. These values can be changed on the 'Hardware Implementation' page of the Configuration Parameters dialog.

Comment: @Ranjan Yes, one of the requirements in the doc I mentioned in my previous comments says "Values must be the same for top and referenced models" for Hardware Implementation. Have you read the doc?

Comment: Yes I read it, that means I can't implement what I wrote above in my query in your suggested way?

Comment: Can you not change the hardware implementation to match? I assume this is simulation only and no hardware is actually used. You can then revert to the original settings when the simulation is finished.

Comment: I think we can't. any other solution if you know?

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't know. To me, that would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run two paraller simulations you can check this Matlab site: http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/running-parallel-simulations.html. Matlab have many guides for their users.